Unsupported methods should written 403
For the URL https://localhost:9443
or as shown in image 
Methods which arw not allowed should return 403.
Added this in my web.xml
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>restricted methods</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>       
  <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
  <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
  <http-method>PATCH</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint/>

But this is not working for me.

Please check your tags: This is certainly not Apache-httpd-related. Also [help/on-topic] and [ask] might give you some hints, as it doesn't seem to be a programming-related problem. At least not the way this question is phrased.
